# exporting regex strings to Android ressources

Tags: android, regex, xml, escaping, lint

I want to export several regex strings to Android string ressources.

Basically Android string ressources are XML, so I need to fulfill the XSD.

On the other hand there is LINT with its ruleset, for example "..." needs to be replaced with ellipsis character …

So in order to write a converter I want to know all the rules I havbe to take care about.

Searching in Stack Overflow I found these rules:
[What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents)

But somehow escaping slash or backslash is not handled there, and the LINT replacements neither.

Comment: Are you aware that you can just ignore Lint if you determined that its rules do not apply in a certain situation?

Comment: Please provide some your strings

Comment: Just escape the characters `"<>&'` and you are fine. `\\ ` can simply be written as `\ `, because it is only necessary to escape a String in Java